# Docker on Windows - HyperV is a must?

Tags: docker-for-windows

I would like to use Docker on Windows Server 2016 Host with **linux containers**

As per my understanding, the different between Docker and VMs is that for Docker we do not need to use HYPERVISOR.

But, i found that when i am installing Docker desktop for windows, it automatically under the hood using Microsoft Hyper-V which is  HYPERVISOR.

Can someone explain what i am missing here?

I know that docker has native support for Windows containers but what about linux containers?

Comment: See [If Docker runs natively on windows, then why does it need hyper-v on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48251703/if-docker-runs-natively-on-windows-then-why-does-it-need-hyper-v)

Comment: @seth that answer not relevant for Linux containers on windows host

Comment: The [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48252608/6590026) to that question actually talks exactly about that case.

Comment: @seth - virtual box is also such of Hypervisor

Comment: Docker Toolbox supports using VirtualBox. It’s unclear what your question is due to the Docker installation and requirements being well documented

Comment: Yes, Virtual Box is also a Hypervisor. But as that answer and the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) states it's not supported (anymore)/a legacy solution. The answer provided also states that you need the VM in order to use Linux containers as you need a Linux in that case and as e.g. WSL isn't supported (yet). So I really don't get why you think that answer isn't applicable to your question or what you find confusing about it?

Answer (score 4):

Docker on Windows requires having an available hypervisor for the virtualization
of the containers.

Docker Desktop for Windows can use Microsoft Hyper-V on Windows 10 / Server 2016.

On other Windows versions, the Docker version called Docker Toolbox uses
Oracle’s VirtualBox as hypervisor and installs it during its installation.
As VirtualBox conflicts with Hyper-V, this version cannot be installed when
Hyper-V is installed.

In addition, VirtualBox does not meet what Docker calls
"minimal system requirements", so Docker Toolbox has degraded capabilities
compared to Docker Desktop for Windows.

Comment: Is docker desktop is the right version to install for production on Windows 2016?

Comment: Yes, I don't think that Docker Toolbox is developed any more.

Comment: Very old, but I'm just reading it: No, Docker Desktop is not what you want to use for a production machine. You want to install the Containers Windows Feature on a Server VM instead.